# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) with Java 10

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I Started getting the following error anytime I try to collect my rdd's. It happened after I installed Java 10.1 So of course I took it out and reinstalled it, same error. I then installed Java 9.04 same error. I then ripped out python 2.7.14, apache spark 2.3.0 and Hadoop 2.7, same error. Does anyone have any one have any other reasons why I keep getting the error?

```py
>>> from operator import add
>>> from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
>>> import string
>>> import sys
>>> import re
>>>
>>> sc = SparkContext(appName="NEW")
2018-04-21 22:28:45 WARN  Utils:66 - Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize(xrange(1,10))
>>> new =rdd.collect()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 824, in collect
    port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "C:\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.6-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
  File "C:\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.6-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:449)
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:262)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2292)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2066)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2092)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:939)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:938)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

>>> print rdd.getNumPartitions()
12
>>>
>>> print(new)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'new' is not defined
>>> sc.stop()
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Does anyone have any one have any other reasons why I keep getting the error?

Current Apache Spark versions don't support Java 9 or later. The support for these (or later versions) is planned for 3.0 release.

For the time being to run Spark you'll have to use JDK 8.

Source:

- [time for Apache Spark 3.0?](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/time-for-Apache-Spark-3-0-td23755.html)
- [SPARK-24417 Build and Run Spark on JDK11](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24417)

Comment: I tried this, reverted java to JDK 8 with spark 2.3.0. Still seeing the same exception. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user87407 If you use PySpark, then it is likely a configuration problem.  Maybe some `JAVA_HOME` or similar hidden somewhere in some configuration file?

Comment: @user8371915, you are right. I had updated the JAVA_HOME, but missed to change it in spark-env.sh. Thanks!

Comment: I faced to the same issue in intellij while working with spark. Its default is jdk 11, replaced with jdk8 and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The issue can be resolved by updating Java to version 8, and modifying to JDK 8. The problem goes away with this configuration:

- JAVA JDK: jdk-8u92-windows-x64
- java version 1.8.0_181

The above is for your reference