# dataframe,Describe() function on spark 2.3.1 is throwing Py4JJavaError

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am using Spark 2.3.1 and python 3.6.5 on ubuntu. While running a dataframe.Describe() function I am getting below error on Jupyter Notebook.

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-19-ea8415b8a3ee> in <module>()
    ----> 1 df.describe()

    ~/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in describe(self, *cols)
       1052         if len(cols) == 1 and isinstance(cols[0], list):
       1053             cols = cols[0]
    -> 1054         jdf = self._jdf.describe(self._jseq(cols))
       1055         return DataFrame(jdf, self.sql_ctx)
       1056 

    ~/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
       1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
       1256         return_value = get_return_value(
    -> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
       1258 
       1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

    ~/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
         61     def deco(*a, **kw):
         62         try:
    ---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
         64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
         65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

    ~/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
        326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
        327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    --> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
        329             else:
        330                 raise Py4JError(

    Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o132.describe.
    : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:449)
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
        at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:262)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2299)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2073)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:939)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:938)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.stat.StatFunctions$.aggResult$lzycompute$1(StatFunctions.scala:273)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.stat.StatFunctions$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$stat$StatFunctions$$aggResult$1(StatFunctions.scala:273)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.stat.StatFunctions$$anonfun$summary$2.apply$mcVI$sp(StatFunctions.scala:286)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.stat.StatFunctions$.summary(StatFunctions.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.summary(Dataset.scala:2473)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.describe(Dataset.scala:2412)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

This is the test code I am using:

```
    import findspark
    findspark.init('/home/pathirippilly/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7')
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    from pyspark.sql.types import  StringType,StructType,StructField,IntegerType
    spark=SparkSession.builder.appName('Basics').getOrCreate()
    df=spark.read.json('people.json')
    df.describe() #not working
    df.describe().show #not working
```

I have installed below versions of java,scala,python and spark.

```
    pathirippilly@sparkBox:/usr/lib/jvm$ java -version

openjdk version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.1+10-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.1+10-Ubuntu-3ubuntu1, mixed mode)

pathirippilly@sparkBox:/usr/lib/jvm$ bashscala -version

Scala code runner version 2.11.12 -- Copyright 2002-2017, LAMP/EPFL

python : 3.6.5

Spark version is spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7
```

And my environmental variable setup is as below. I have saved all these variables in /etc/environment and invoking it through /etc/bash.bashbrc

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
PYSPARK_DRIVER_OPTION="jupyter"
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
SPARK_HOME='/home/pathirippilly/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/'
PATH=$SPARK_HOME:$PATH
PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/
```

Also I have not configured spark_env.sh.Is it neccessary to have spark_env.sh configured?

Is it because of any comparability issue ? Or Am i doing something wrong here?

It will be really helpful if some one can route me to the right direction here.

Note:df.show() is working perfect for the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to fix rdd.collect() error after installing java 10.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49961991/how-to-fix-rdd-collect-error-after-installing-java-10-1)

Comment: Probably, your json have illegal argument in any keys? 
Try `spark.read.option("charset", "UTF-8").json('people.json')`

Comment: @user8371915 I have edited and added my **python/java/scala/spark** versions and **environmental variables** to the original question. I am not using spark_env.sh for any kind of configuration . I have checked the spark2.3.1 release document and the versions of java I am using is seems to be compatible.Can you please help me to find if my configuration is fine by looking at my environmental variable set up?

Comment: It is not compatible. You use Java 10 or 11, while Spark supports only Java 8.

Comment: @sailesh I have tried it, but no luck. I tested the error using a small data frame of 2 rows and columns. Still _.describe()_ , _.count()_, _.sum()_ ..etc functions are not working for the spark data frame. My spark session is getting created successfully and _.Show()_, ._printschema()_ are working fine too.

Comment: @user8371915 I have installed java 8 and both **JAVA_HOME** and **PATH** variable are reset to _java8_ _jdk_. I have jus checked with _java_  _-version_ command , it also returning java 8 only. But still I am getting same error for **Describe()** and **Describe().show()** functions. I have restarted the terminal as well as jupyter notebook. Any other areas to reset or check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue fixed for me. I have reconfigured entire set up from beginning.And I have prepared my /etc/environment file as below

```
    export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/$
    export SPARK_HOME='/home/pathirippilly/spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7'
    export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHONPATH
    export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON='jupyter'
    export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
    export PYSPARK_PYTHONPATH=python3
    export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"
    export PATH=$SPARK_HOME:$PATH:~/.local/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin
```

And I have added below line to /etc/bash.bashrc

```
    source /etc/environment
```

**Note:**
*

1. *My pyspark is available in my PYTHONPATH, so since everytime when I
   open a session in my terminal /etc/bash.bashrc will do source
   /etc/environment which will inturn export all the environmental
   variables*
2. *I have used java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 instead of java 10 or 11.  But
   I think 10 or 11 also will work as per pyspark 2.3.1 release
   document.Not sure.*
3. *I have used scala 2.11.12 only.*
4. *My py4j module is also available in my PTHONPATH.*

I am not sure where I had messed up before. But now with above set up my pyspark 2.3.1
is working fine with Java1.8,Scala 2.11.12,Python 3.6.5 (and without findspark module)

Answer (score 2):

OP, I'm having exactly the same setup as you had, in fact we are following the same Spark course in Udemy *(setting up everything they say to the letter)* and encountered the same error at the same place. The only thing I changed for it to work was the Java version. When the course was made,
`$ sudo apt-get install default-jre`
installed 8, but now it installs 11. I then uninstalled that Java and ran
`$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre`
then changed the JAVA_HOME path to point to it and now it works.

Comment: Yeah..even I have used Java 10 at the beginning.Later changed to 8. But Then why the spark authors are saying below line in spark 2.3.1 release doc?
        `Spark runs on Java 8+, Python 2.7+/3.4+ and R 3.1+. For the Scala API, 
        Spark 2.3.1 uses Scala 2.11. You will need to use a compatible Scala 
         version (2.11.x)`
Does Java 8+ means only Java 8 versions or Java 8 and above?
Any way by configuring bash.bashrc file as I have explained in below section, Now I can run or import pyspark from any where in local without using 'findspark'

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error while following the same Spark course in Udemy.Below are the steps I have followed to resolve the issue.

Removing openjdk version 11 :

1)sudo apt-get autoremove default-jdk openjdk-11-jdk
It would ask for confirmation,please provide the same.
2)sudo apt-get remove default-jre.

Installing jdk 8 and configuring the same
3)sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
Pointing JAVA_HOME to this newly installed jdk
4)export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"

Following above approach the error from df.describe() got resolved.