# spark-shell throwing exceptions

Tags: python-3.x, scala, apache-spark

Error while trying to run spark-shell. Pyspark runs perfectly. Not sure what the issue is.

Tried changing paths in the ~/.bash_profile. Nothing worked.
Tried uninstalling and again installing packages.

I have listed the msgs that are displayed on the terminal below. 
New to Spark and Scala. Hence, need some help in setting up of the system. Can someone look into the code and let me know what has gone wrong.

---

```
MacBook-Pro:spark zoo$ bin/spark-shell
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil (file:/usr/local/spark/jars/hadoop-auth-2.7.3.jar) to method sun.security.krb5.Config.getInstance()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.KerberosUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2019-01-26 11:32:29 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).

Failed to initialize compiler: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
** Note that as of 2.8 scala does not assume use of the java classpath.
** For the old behavior pass -usejavacp to scala, or if using a Settings
** object programmatically, settings.usejavacp.value = true.

Failed to initialize compiler: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
** Note that as of 2.8 scala does not assume use of the java classpath.
** For the old behavior pass -usejavacp to scala, or if using a Settings
** object programmatically, settings.usejavacp.value = true.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.exitingPhase(SymbolTable.scala:256)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.x$20$lzycompute(IMain.scala:896)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.x$20(IMain.scala:895)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.headerPreamble$lzycompute(IMain.scala:895)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.headerPreamble(IMain.scala:895)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$Wrapper.preamble(IMain.scala:918)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$CodeAssembler$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(IMain.scala:1337)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$CodeAssembler$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(IMain.scala:1336)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.package$.stringFromWriter(package.scala:64)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$CodeAssembler$class.apply(IMain.scala:1336)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$Wrapper.apply(IMain.scala:908)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.compile$lzycompute(IMain.scala:1002)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.compile(IMain.scala:997)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.compile(IMain.scala:579)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:567)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(SparkILoop.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.apply(SparkILoop.scala:79)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:79)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.savingReplayStack(ILoop.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:78)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:110)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:920)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

#

```
MacBook-Pro:spark zoo$ cat ~/.bash_profile

# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"

export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark
export SBT_HOME=/usr/local/sbt
export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/scala

export PATH="$PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin"
export PYTHONPATH="$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHONPATH"
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$SBT_HOME/bin:$SBT_HOME/lib:$SCALA_HOME/bin:$SCALA_HOME/lib:$PATH
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin:$PATH

export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
```

Comment: Spark doesn't support Java >= 9 - [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) with Java 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49961991/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-at-org-apache-xbean-asm5-classreader-initu)

Comment: Thankyou. Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

The java classpath is not correctly set. Luckily the error message explains exactly how to fix it.

> ** Note that as of 2.8 scala does not assume use of the java classpath.
>   ** For the old behavior pass -usejavacp to scala, or if using a Settings
>   ** object programmatically, settings.usejavacp.value = true.

Just adding the `-usejavacp` parameter when stating spark-shell is the simplest fix.   So you would run it as `spark-shell -usejavacp`.

It also looks like you are using a version of Java newer than Java 8, which is not supported.  The warnings about illegal reflective access are signs of this.  You may need to install Java8 as well and use that when running spark-shell.