# scala.ScalaReflectionException: class java.sql.Timestamp in JavaMirror with ClasspathFilter

Tags: java, scala, unit-testing, apache-spark

I have a unit test that basically converts dataframe to dataset using a case class.

When i run that test using JDK 8 it passes but when I use JDK 10 or 11 it fails saying:

> scala.ScalaReflectionException: class java.sql.Timestamp in JavaMirror with ClasspathFilter

There isn't any other information I get from failure message. My unit test looks like:

```scala
"A dataFrameToDataSet function" should "return DataSet[AssetTagAsset] from dataframe that contains Asset data" in {

  val assetTagAssets = Map[Long, AssetTagAsset](
    (
      1L,
      new AssetTagAsset(
        asset_tag_asset_id = 1L,
        asset_tag_asset_uuid = "test",
        asset_id = 1L,
        asset_tag_id = 1L,
        sticky = "abc",
        added_date = Option(Timestamp.valueOf("2018-04-17 10:10:50")),
        added_user_id = Option(1L),
        region = "sjc01",
        environment = "eng",
        pod = "p05"
      )
    )
  )

  val DecimalType = DataTypes.createDecimalType(38, 10)

  val assetTagAssetSchema = List(
    StructField("ASSET_TAG_ASSET_ID", DecimalType, false),
    StructField("ASSET_TAG_ASSET_UUID", StringType, false),
    StructField("ASSET_ID", DecimalType, false),
    StructField("ASSET_TAG_ID", DecimalType, false),
    StructField("STICKY", StringType, false),
    StructField("ADDED_DATE", TimestampType, true),
    StructField("ADDED_USER_ID", DecimalType, true),
    StructField("REGION", StringType, false),
    StructField("ENVIRONMENT", StringType, false),
    StructField("POD", StringType, false)
  )

  val assetTagAssetRows = assetTagAssets.values
    .map(
      assetTagAsset =>
        Row(
          java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf(assetTagAsset.asset_tag_asset_id),
          assetTagAsset.asset_tag_asset_uuid,
          java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf(assetTagAsset.asset_id),
          java.math.BigDecimal.valueOf(assetTagAsset.asset_tag_id),
          assetTagAsset.sticky,
          assetTagAsset.added_date.orNull,
          toBigDecimal(assetTagAsset.added_user_id),
          assetTagAsset.region,
          assetTagAsset.environment,
          assetTagAsset.pod
       )
     )
     .toSeq

  val assetTagAssetDF = spark.createDataFrame(
    spark.sparkContext.parallelize(assetTagAssetRows),
    StructType(assetTagAssetSchema)
  )

  val ds = dataFrameToDataSet[AssetTagAsset]("oracle_grc_asset_tag_asset", assetTagAssetDF)
  assert(ds.count() === assetTagAssets.size)

  ds.collect.foreach(assetTagAsset => {
    val expectedAssetTagAsset = assetTagAssets(assetTagAsset.asset_tag_asset_id)
    assert(assetTagAsset.asset_tag_asset_uuid === expectedAssetTagAsset.asset_tag_asset_uuid)
    assert(assetTagAsset.asset_id === expectedAssetTagAsset.asset_id)
    assert(assetTagAsset.asset_tag_id === expectedAssetTagAsset.asset_tag_id)
    assert(assetTagAsset.sticky === expectedAssetTagAsset.sticky)
    assert(assetTagAsset.added_date === expectedAssetTagAsset.added_date)
    assert(assetTagAsset.added_user_id === expectedAssetTagAsset.added_user_id)
    assert(assetTagAsset.region === expectedAssetTagAsset.region)
    assert(assetTagAsset.environment === expectedAssetTagAsset.environment)
    assert(assetTagAsset.pod === expectedAssetTagAsset.pod)
  })
}
```

AssetTagAsset is a case class that looks like:

```scala
case class AssetTagAsset(
  asset_tag_asset_id: Long,
  asset_tag_asset_uuid: String,
  asset_id: Long,
  asset_tag_id: Long,
  sticky: String,
  added_date: Option[java.sql.Timestamp],
  added_user_id: Option[Long],
  region: String,
  environment: String,
  pod: String
)
  def apply(row: Row): AssetTagAsset = {
    new AssetTagAsset(
      asset_tag_asset_id = row.getAs[java.math.BigDecimal]("ASSET_TAG_ASSET_ID").longValue,
      asset_tag_asset_uuid = row.getAs[String]("ASSET_TAG_ASSET_UUID"),
      asset_id = row.getAs[java.math.BigDecimal]("ASSET_ID").longValue,
      asset_tag_id = row.getAs[java.math.BigDecimal]("ASSET_TAG_ID").longValue,
      sticky = row.getAs[String]("STICKY"),
      added_date = getOptionValue(row, "ADDED_DATE"),
      added_user_id = getOptionValue(row, "ADDED_USER_ID"),
      region = row.getAs[String]("REGION"),
      environment = row.getAs[String]("ENVIRONMENT"),
      pod = row.getAs[String]("POD")
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure JDK10/11 is supported with Spark yet.

Comment: It does support. take a look https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/

Comment: Spark runs on Java 8+, Python 2.7+/3.4+ and R 3.1+. For the Scala API, Spark 2.4.0 uses Scala 2.11. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.11.x).
And i am using spark 2.4

Comment: What you quote doesn't necessarily mean it supports Java 10 - it might just be the Java 8 and 9. In fact, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49964607/7470253) Spark prior to version 3.0 doesn't even support Java 9, limit is 8 only.

Comment: Not sure the documentation is correct. I have seen a lot of issues going through RE: JDK 10. The + in 8+ is probably wrong. Spark runs on Scala and I am not sure that Scala, even 2.12, supports JDK > 8 (see https://www.scala-lang.org/download/)

Comment: @jgp i think that might be the case. But take a look for jvm-scala compatibility version: 
https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html

Comment: But i guess downgrading my java version is better option from what @M.Prokhorov suggested. Thanks