# Tests fail on a simple RDD action

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, rdd, scalatest

I am currently trying to package my project using maven, however, maven tests fail (throws an exception) on a simple RDD action.

> I am using Spark 2.3.0, Scala 2.11.8, JDK 8.

The code:

```
class A extends FunSuite with DataFrameSuiteBase with Matchers with Logging
                                          with BeforeAndAfter with MockFactory {
    val myList= List(
        Array(22, 34, 56, 785),
        Array(21,24,34,534,563),
        Array(2, 34, 86,345),
        Array(10, 34, 98),
        Array(101, 456, 545,678,763),
        Array(1, 3, 5,23),
        Array(32, 322, 523,623),
        Array(11, 22, 58,223),
        Array(14, 545),
        Array(22)
    )
    val myRDD: RDD[Array[Int]] = sc.parallelize(myList)

    test("rddTest"){
       val byValueCount = myRDD.flatMap(x => x).countByValue() //doesn't work
       val rddCount = myRDD.count() //works
    ...}}
```

The second count is working fine, but the first count (by value) throws this exception:

```
- rddTest *** FAILED ***
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
  at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:46)
  at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:449)
  at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:103)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:103)
  at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
  at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:432)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.a(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:262)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:261)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:159)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2292)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2066)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2092)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:939)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:938)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$countByKey$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:370)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$countByKey$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:370)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.countByKey(PairRDDFunctions.scala:369)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$countByValue$1.apply(RDD.scala:1208)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$countByValue$1.apply(RDD.scala:1208)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.countByValue(RDD.scala:1207)
```

**The tests are just fine using the IDE (intelliJ).**

***EDIT: FULLL POM***:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>project_2.11</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <description>project</description>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>project</name>
    <organization>
        <name>project</name>
    </organization>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
        <scala.compat.version>2.11</scala.compat.version>
        <spark.cdh.version>${spark.version}.cloudera1</spark.cdh.version>
        <mockito.version>1.9.5</mockito.version>
        <spark.version>2.3.0</spark.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- repository to add org.apache.spark -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cloudera-repo-releases</id>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala-2.10</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <!-- regular resource processsing for everything except logback.xml -->
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process-test</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                    <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- enable scalatest -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>false</parallel>
                    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                    <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                    <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
                    <htmlreporters>${project.build.directory}/html/scalatest</htmlreporters>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                    <!--<argLine>-Xmx2048m</argLine>-->
                    <argLine>-Xmx2048m -Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true</argLine>
                    <stdout>F</stdout>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pegdown</groupId>
            <artifactId>pegdown</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>project-utils</groupId>
            <artifactId>project-utils_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>project-common</groupId>
            <artifactId>project-common_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scoverage</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalac-scoverage-runtime_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scoverage</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalac-scoverage-plugin_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>runtime</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.holdenkarau</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-testing-base_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}_0.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalaz</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalaz-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalamock</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalamock_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalamock</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalamock-scalatest-support_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fommil.netlib</groupId>
            <artifactId>all</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

*The answers online are for those who use Java 9+ - I'm using Java 8.
The previous solutions were on this: [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) with Java 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49961991/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-at-org-apache-xbean-asm5-classreader-initu)*

*However, it's not a solution for my case.
Also, this is a very focused problem and by no means a duplicate.*

**Thank you very much!**

Comment: You might want to provide a [mcve] - in this case it would be a project layout and complete source, in addition to reproducible build definition. Also, I'd recommend illustrating how you determine Java version (looking at `JAVA_HOME` and `java -version` as seen by Maven, would be a good place to start. Note that `maven-compiler-plugin` settings and JDK in use, are two different things). Finally description and what you've shared from `pom.xml` doesn't seem to match - one refers to Scala 2.11, other to 2.10.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did my best to give a clean, minimal and complete verifiable example. About the Maven - as you can see I use a plugin to set the exact Java version I want to use. I also made sure the JAVA_HOME is set to the right JDK (the only JDK I have), and used mvn -version And it is 1.8 as I said.

Comment: Side question - why there are scoverage dependencies in your project. There shouldn't be any.

Comment: I am using scoverage dependencies to make a test coverage report. what I shared is only a snippet, one of the tests I run. However, I did try and remove those - it still didn't made a difference. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was conflicting dependencies as ALincoln suspected. Some other modules in the same project (even though they are not related) had conflicts with this one.
Apparently the root pom made a connection with unrelated modules and the final result was this error. Thank you, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Your code works just fine on my machine (Spark 2.3.0 or Spark 2.3.1). I think it is some mess with dependencies. Please provide full pom.xml.

Comment: I added the full pom, thank you!
I also edit the classes I inherit to use the tests.

Comment: Your pom is ok, except for some of the dependencies which refer to other internal projects: project-utils_2.11, project-common_2.11. Those I commented out and it works fine from IntelliJ and using mvn from command line: 

Tests: succeeded 1, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
All tests passed.
BUILD SUCCESS