# Spark for Java 11

Tags: apache-spark, java-11

Spark 2.x when being used for Java 11 gives below error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 55

Does Spark 3.0 has this compatibility with Java 11?

Is there any another workaround to use Java 11 with Spark?

Answer (score 11):

From [Spark 3 documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/#downloading):

> Spark runs on Java 8/11, Scala 2.12, Python 2.7+/3.4+ and R 3.1+. Java 8 prior to version 8u92 support is deprecated as of Spark 3.0.0. Python 2 and Python 3 prior to version 3.6 support is deprecated as of Spark 3.0.0. R prior to version 3.4 support is deprecated as of Spark 3.0.0. For the Scala API, Spark 3.0.0 uses Scala 2.12. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.12.x).

So Spark 3.x works with Java11, Spark 2.x does not as pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49961991/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-at-org-apache-xbean-asm5-classreader-initu).

Answer (score 0):

For java 11 we have spark-streaming_2.12 artifact with 3.1.1 version