# JDK version issue (ASM5 unable to create annotation scanner exception)

Tags: java, maven, java-8, java-11, apache-tomee

I was recently working on 2 different projects, one was based on Tomee and JDK8 and the other one on Quarkus and JDK11. After I switched my env. variables to point to JDK8 I suddenly can't build my JDK8 based project.

I get the following exception:

```
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/app]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:988)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1860)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to create annotation scanner for web module app: null
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2305)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1188)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1125)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5105)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Unable to create annotation scanner for web module app: null
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:886)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.load(DeploymentLoader.java:233)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.loadApplication(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:2303)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm5.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.readClassDef(AnnotationFinder.java:1169)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.<init>(AnnotationFinder.java:147)
    at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.<init>(AnnotationFinder.java:160)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory$OpenEJBAnnotationFinder.<init>(FinderFactory.java:546)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.newFinder(FinderFactory.java:267)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.create(FinderFactory.java:80)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.FinderFactory.createFinder(FinderFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.openejb.config.DeploymentLoader.addWebModule(DeploymentLoader.java:878)
    ... 18 more
```

I have also tried reinstalling JDK.

Output of `java -version` is:

```
java version "1.8.0_291"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_291-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.291-b10, mixed mode)
```

I build project using Maven from console and not IDE and use Maven Tomee plugin to run it:

```
mvn tomee:run
```

Output of `mvn -version` is:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\Dev\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_291, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

I also checked IntelliJ settings, even though I'm not running the app through IDE but in a separate shell.

Comment: You need to detail out what you mean by *"After I switched my env. variables to point to JDK8"*.

Comment: @Naman It means after I change JAVA_HOME to point back to JDK8 directory.

Comment: Check that your project is truly using Java 8 not Java 11. There are compatibility issues with that class in the asm5 package on Java 9 and later. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49961991/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-at-org-apache-xbean-asm5-classreader-initu

Comment: @jbx I have copied outputs of checking Java versions, I'm not sure what else I should check, version in use seems to be 8, but the exception is still there when trying to start the application.

Comment: uninstall JDK11 and see what happens. Also check you are not using the IDE's bundled JDK.

Comment: @jbx I removed all other versions of JDK I had, IntelliJ doesn't come with bundled JDK (at least for Windows).

Comment: Yes IntelliJ comes with bundled JDK also on windows. It is under the jbr directory. But if you are having this issue also outside the IDE it is probably not the problem.

Comment: Have you tried `mvn clean` before running your programm? Maybe you have accidentally compiled some classes with Java 11.

Comment: @Itchy I did `mvn clean install` every time so I have appropriate .war version in my local repo. I even checked manifest of compiled .war and build line says: `Build-Jdk-Spec: 1.8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved by removing all of the JDK-s, removing maven, deleting local .m2 directory, removing checked out projects, removing all env. variables related to JDK or Maven.

- Installed JDK 1.8
- Installed latest version of maven
- Cloned project from repo again
- Compiled and ran project successfully